# How to show delete button only if the comment is made by the user logged in?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a `ListView` which displays all the comments made by users on a specific news article.

I want to let the user who created a comment to also be able to delete it, so a deletion button should be visible to him and only him, near the comment(s) made by him.

Taking into account that it is not allowed to set the visible property using `<%= ... %>` in a server tag, how should one do it?

I though about iterating through all the `ListView` items and add the button if necessary, but I think it is too much hassle and there is a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to set the visible property in the `ItemTemplate` of your `ListView`, could you show the code in the view?

Comment: I think you're on the right track. You'll have to go through each row OnRowDataBound (or similar, i forget the event exactly), compare the curr user with the user ID in the row and show/hide the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the visibility logic on the ListView ItemDataBound event.

Markup:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv" OnItemDataBound="ItemDataBound" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        var deleteButton = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("DeleteButtonID");

        YourDataSource yourDataSource = e.Item.DataItem as YourDataSource;
        deleteButton.Visible = yourDataSource.CanDelete;
    }
}
```